# I am getting an unresolved identifier even though I have a let for the variable

Tags: swift

I set the constant calculationError inside the structure PendingBinaryOperation
I create a variable pendingBinaryOperation of type PendingBinaryOperation
I get the error in a case statement that calculationError is an unresolved identifier.  The section of the code is below.

```
mutating func performOperation(_ symbol:String){
    if let currentOperation = operations[symbol] {
        switch currentOperation {
        case .nullOperation(let function, let nullDiscription):
            accumulator = (function(), nullDiscription, nil)
        case .constant(let value):
            accumulator = (value,symbol, nil)
        case .unaryOperation(let function, let unaryDescription, let unaryMemory):
            if accumulator != nil {
                accumulator = (function(accumulator!.digit), unaryDescription(accumulator!.description),
                unaryMemory(accumulator!.digit))
            }
        case .binaryOperation(let binaryFunction,
                              let binaryDescription,
                              let binaryError):
            if accumulator != nil {
                doAPendingBinaryOperation()
                resultIsPending = true
                pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(
                    mathFunction: binaryFunction,
                    calculationDescription:binaryDescription,
                    firstOperand: accumulator!.digit,
                    descriptionOperand:(accumulator?.description)!,
 THIS LINE GIVES THE ERROR ->binaryError: calculationError) 
                accumulator = nil
            }
        case .equals:
            doAPendingBinaryOperation()
            resultIsPending = false
        }
    }
}

private var pendingBinaryOperation:PendingBinaryOperation?

struct PendingBinaryOperation {
    let calculationError: (Double, Double) -> String
    let mathFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
    let calculationDescription: (String, String) -> String
    let firstOperand: (Double)
    let descriptionOperand:(String)
    func perform(with secondOperand:(Double)) -> Double {
        return (mathFunction(firstOperand, secondOperand))
    }
    func performDecription(with secondOperan:(String)) -> String {
        return (calculationDescription(descriptionOperand, secondOperan))
    }
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a playground and virtually every line is flagged as an error. Can you post code that only produces the error you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you show, the constructor for `PendingBinaryOperation` is:

```
PendingBinaryOperation(calculationError: (Double, Double) -> String, mathFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double, calculationDescription: (String, String) -> String, firstOperand: (Double), descriptionOperand: (String))
```

but you are calling:

```
PendingBinaryOperation(mathFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double, calculationDescription: (String, String) -> String, firstOperand: (Double), descriptionOperand:(String), binaryError: ??)
```

As you can see, the order of your parameters are all wrong, and you have a parameter called `binaryError` that doesn't exist in the type.

I'm guessing you need to reverse `binaryError: calculationError` to `calculationError: binaryError` and re-order your parameters so they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Structs in Swift automatically generate a memberwise initializer, that's what you're using here to initialize `PendingBinaryOperation`. This requires that *all properties* be set in the initializer, including `binaryError`.

You're trying to pass `calculationError` as the value of the `binaryError` argument - this is not possible as `calculationError` is unavailable in this scope (and has no value).

If you don't want to set `binaryError`, you'll have to abandon using the memberwise initializer. This usually means giving add of `PendingBinaryOperation` properties an initial value, and using the normal `init` (i.e. `PendingBinaryOperation()`).